# Bubble sort performance

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

If bubble sort takes 200 sec to sort 200 names then how many items it can sort in 800 secs?

Calculating number of comparisons can give us the solution. How can we calculate the number of comparisons it takes to sort 200 names ? Do we have to consider the best case ?

Comment: The time bubblesort takes depends not only on the length of the input but also on its structure, so you can't make a calculation like that.

Comment: @rohit jain: yes it is .. but i know i need to calculate the number of comparisons only thing is i don't know how to do it in case of bubble sort!? :|

Comment: @user975234: you need to read the code (or at least a description of the algorithm). Unfortunately you don't have enough information anyway, because all you know is that 200s was somewhere in the range of possibilities for 200 names. You don't know whether it was a best case or a worst case, and the difference between the two is a factor of approximately 100 times as many comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bubble sort is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Do your maths. Big O just gives an idea of relative time, you can guess rough estimate of time. Not exact.
2. BubbleSort takes n-1 comparisons in first go, n-2 in second, and so on. So you have total `(n-1) + (n-2) + .. +1`. Do some maths again?
3. <strike>Bubble Sort is so pathetic that there is no best case!</strike><sup>[1]</sup>

(obviously you can write a smart bubble sort that does not sort an already sorted array)

```
BUBBLESORT A
 for i = 1 to A.length 1
  for j = A.length downto i+1
    if A[j]  < A[j - 1]
     exchange A[j] with A[j-1]
```

from The Introduction to Algorithms - CLRS

---

[1] On #3. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort it mentions an optimized inner loop that identified the sorted remaining array and makes a best case O(n) -- sorry about that.

Comment: (3) is false. The best case for bubble sort is when the input is already sorted, in which case it does only a single scan over the data performing *n*-1 comparisons and no swaps.

Comment: @larsmans I guess the algorithm I pasted here would take O(n*n) anyway. Isn't it? Assuming comparison is O(1)

Comment: @Nishant: if we take number of comparisons n-1 + n-2 + n-3 ... we get total number of comparisons as, n(1-n)/2 .. now making use of this equations gives me -ve number of comparisons for 200 names as, 200*(-199)/2 ?? :|

Comment: @Nishant: yes, the CLRS version always takes Θ(n²) time. The [version on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation) is smarter.

Comment: take the generalized form .. (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) ... gives, (n+n+n+n+n+ ..... ) - (1+2+3+ ... ) = n - n(n+1)/2 = n(1-n)/2!

Comment: in your case n = 200; so you have `199 + 198+ ... +1` [sum of first N natural numbers](http://www.9math.com/book/sum-first-n-natural-numbers)? `n*(n+1)/2 = 199*200/2 = 19,900`. got it?

Comment: BTW your maths is terrible :) `(n+n+n+n+n+ ..... ) - (1+2+3+ ... )  = n*n -(n*n +n)/2 = (n*n - n)/2 = n(n-1)/2 => 200*199/2`!

Comment: yeah .. got it :P . i knw its terrible! :D

Comment: The question actually makes a lot more sense if we *do* assume a completely stupid Bubble Sort that doesn't bail out early when it makes a sweep with no changes. Because then the time spent doing swaps still depends on the data, but the number of comparisons doesn't and so the overall time is at least close to being proportional to n^2.

Comment: `takes n-1 comparisons in first go, n-2 in second, and so on. So you have total (n-1) + (n-2) + .. +1.` Do you mean swaps or comparisons? Isn't the number of comparisons constant (n-1) for each loop?

Answer (score 1):

800 is 4 x 200. Bubble sort is O(n*n), so on average you can sort twice as many items in 4 times the time, so the expectation is 400 names, on average, if 200 was an average case.